# MKLINK /D Symlink Weird Behavior Windows 10

Tags: windows, network-shares, symbolic-link

I have a home file server running Windows 10 Pro.

On my server PC I have a folder:

`F:\DATA\BACKUPS` set up as a hidden share `\\SERVER\BACKUPS$`

I have a network folder called `D:\Files` shared as `\\SERVER\FILES`

I created a symlink in the D:\Files location to the BACKUPS folder

`MKLINK /D "D:\FILES\BACKUPS" "\\SERVER\BACKUPS$"`

On the host server, I can access the symlink BACKUP folder just fine either from `D:\Files` or `\\SERVER\FILES`

From a client PC, however, I get an error: `\\SERVER\FILES\BACKUPS\ is not accessible`

I check the properties of the symlink and it says target: `\\SERVER\BACKUPS$`

So I'm not sure why it's looking for `\\SERVER\FILES\BACKUPS` instead  of just `\\SERVER\BACKUPS$`

I was able to just create a shortcut link to it and it works fine. But it seems a symlink should work too.

Comment: Mhm I had a similar issue and in that case the issue was, that the link redirected to a local folder. Instead of the remote one (resulting in the same error).